# When I run Phpunit with the flag coverage, the error appear: Undefined variable factory

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, phpunit, laravel-6

I use the framework Laravel with the package [modularization](https://github.com/nWidart/laravel-modules).

I created a module and performed some tests on it. However, I can't run my tests with the coverage (`./vendor/bin/phpunit --coverage-text --colors=never`). Without the coverage flag, the tests are running correctly (`./vendor/bin/phpunit`).

here are the two commands executed:

[image]

Among all my tests there is one test I do calls the factory

```
class InstitutionControllerTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * @testdox Get the data of institutions
     * @covers \Modules\Institution\Http\Controllers\InstitutionController::index
     * */
    public function testIndex():void
    {
        $institution = factory(Institution::class)->make();
        $institutionCollection = new Collection($institution);
        $mock = Mockery::mock(InstitutionRepository::class);
        $mock->shouldReceive('all')->andReturn($institutionCollection);
        $this->app->instance(InstitutionRepository::class, $mock);
        $response = $this->json('GET', 'api/institutions');
        $this->assertEquals(Response::HTTP_OK, $response->status());
        $this->assertEquals($institutionCollection, $response->getContent());
    }
}
```

I added the factory to the provide as it is said in the [documentation](https://nwidart.com/laravel-modules/v6/advanced-tools/module-resources) but it doesn't fix the error.

```
class InstitutionServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
       ...
        $this->registerFactories();
       ...
    }
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->register(RouteServiceProvider::class);
        $this->app->singleton(Factory::class, function () {
            $faker = $this->app->make(\Faker\Generator::class);
            return Factory::construct($faker, __DIR__ . '/../Database/factories');
        });
    }
...
    public function registerFactories()
    {
        if (! app()->environment('production') && $this->app->runningInConsole()) {
            app(Factory::class)->load(__DIR__ . '/../Database/factories');
        }
    }
....
}
```

Do you know how I can solve this error ?

phpunit.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit backupGlobals="false"
         backupStaticAttributes="false"
         bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
         colors="true"
         convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
         convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
         convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
         processIsolation="false"
         stopOnFailure="false">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Unit">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Unit/</directory>
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./Modules/**/Tests/Unit/</directory>
        </testsuite>

        <testsuite name="Feature">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Feature/</directory>
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./Modules/**/Tests/Feature</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <filter>
        <whitelist processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
            <directory suffix=".php">./app</directory>
            <directory suffix=".php">./Modules</directory>
            <exclude>
                <directory suffix="blade.php">./Modules</directory>
                <directory suffix=".php">./Modules/**/Routes</directory>
                <directory suffix=".php">./Modules/**/Resources</directory>
                <directory suffix=".php">./Modules/**/Tests</directory>
                <directory suffix=".php">./Modules/**/Config</directory>
            </exclude>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
    <php>
        <server name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
        <server name="BCRYPT_ROUNDS" value="4"/>
        <server name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <server name="MAIL_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <server name="QUEUE_CONNECTION" value="sync"/>
        <server name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
    </php>
</phpunit>
```

My factory class

```
<?php

/** @var \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factory $factory */

use Faker\Generator as Faker;
use Modules\Institution\Entities\Institution;

// the variable $factory is Undefined
$factory->define(Institution::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'name' => $faker->company
    ];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you Xdebug installed on your machine ?

To generate a code coverage, Php Unit isn't enough it needs Xdebug

Answer (score 0):

add these flags to your test CLI run command

```
   --strict-coverage
   --verbose
   --stop-on-defect            
   --stop-on-error             
   --stop-on-failure           
   --stop-on-warning
```

more info on [available flags](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/8.3/textui.html)

perform search in the test source for the `factory` without dollar sign in front of it.

you may also narrow the area of generating this warning by using these flags

```
--group
```

or

```
--filter
```

to run test selectively and see what test method exactly produces this warning.

for group just make an annotation `@group one`, `@group two`, etc.. in all test methods and run test with the flag

```
--group one
```

to run the test method that has the annotation `@group one`.

Comment: I added the flags in the command but it doesn't work, I have the same error. In addition, I did a search for the factory variable throughout the project and there is no bad syntax (for example, see if factory doesn't have a`$` in front). Do you think it could be the error of my `phpunit.xml` file ?

Comment: I found where the error comes from, it comes when I create a factory class. But I don't know solve this

Comment: @diego edit you question and add the factory code + mark exactly where the problem appears.